# Always open all applications in full screen at OS startup

Tags: macos, pdf, big-sur

There are many discussions on how to open Applications in full screen in macOS, like https://osxdaily.com/2018/05/15/make-apps-open-full-screen-mac-automatically/

But there are still many stubborn applications which fail to open in full screen with above approach. One such application is the Foxit PDF reader.

Is there any command line approach to force such individual applications to open full screen when the OS start? Alternatively, is there any way to force **ALL** applications to open in full screen in Mac?

I am using macOS Big Sur.

There is a similar approach available with `Ubuntu` as discussed in https://askubuntu.com/questions/27826/how-to-configure-my-system-so-that-all-windows-start-maximized, I hope to get similar thing for my `Mac` as well.

Thanks for your valuable advice.

Comment: What happens if you press Command + Enter ?

Comment: In some cases, the applications open at start-up (automatically). So command+enter would not come into picture

Comment: I am little bit confused. If statement 'in some cases' is correct then it means that there are  also 'some other cases' as well and therefore command+enter should come into the picture. If the question is how to make applications which are opened at start-up fullscreen then maybe it's worth to clarfiy that in the question body.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg - Just to make this clear: Command + Enter is not working for me. However I am not really concerned for that. I need to have fullscreen approach at startup everytime an App is opened. I will modify the question.